# string representation of F# function signature

Tags: f#, jupyter, let

When I'm working in the F# REPL `fsharpi` whenever I enter a new function the signature is printed after I've entered them:

```
> let foo x = x;;
val foo : x:'a -> 'a
```

Is there a way to retrieve this as a string? The reason I'm asking is that I'm using IfSharp for Jupyter notebooks which doesn't display the signatures, but I'd like to be able to show the types of functions for demonstration purposes.

I've messed around a bit but can't get anything useful, I've tried:

```
let foo x = (x, x)
printfn "%A" (foo.GetType())
printfn "%A" foo
```

But this isn't quite what I need:

```
FSI_0013+clo@3-1
<fun:it@5-2>
```

Is it possible to access this at all?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's actually a function in the F# lib that does this, unfortunately. However it might not be that hard to write your own function for this.

Comment: Dotnet Interactive is available as a [nuget package](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive). It may have a good method for this

Comment: F# interactive is also exposed in the [compiler nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Compiler.Service/).
[FsiValuePrinter](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/efeb98e48ec0e37807fa822cd61d43cc3b04ea7f/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs#L314) looks promising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no function in FSharp.Core for getting a type's string representation as it would appear to the compiler (though maybe there's something in FSharp.Compiler.Services -- I haven't checked). Here's a small function that works for most simple uses:

```
open System

let (|TFunc|_|) (typ: Type) =
    if typ.IsGenericType && typ.GetGenericTypeDefinition () = typeof<int->int>.GetGenericTypeDefinition () then
        match typ.GetGenericArguments() with
        | [|targ1; targ2|] -> Some (targ1, targ2)
        | _ -> None
    else
        None

let rec typeStr (typ: Type) =
    match typ with
    | TFunc (TFunc(_, _) as tfunc, t) -> sprintf "(%s) -> %s" (typeStr tfunc) (typeStr t)
    | TFunc (t1, t2) -> sprintf "%s -> %s" (typeStr t1) (typeStr t2)
    | typ when typ = typeof<int> -> "int"
    | typ when typ = typeof<string> -> "string"
    | typ when typ.IsGenericParameter -> sprintf "'%s" (string typ)
    | typ -> string typ


typeStr typeof<(string -> (string -> int) -> int) -> int>
// val it: string = "string -> (string -> int) -> int"
typeStr (typeof<int->int>.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
// val it: string = "'T -> 'TResult"
```

You can easily write a function on top of this to use `typeStr` on a value's type:

```
let valTypeString x = typStr (x.GetType ())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can analyze types representing F# functions, with the help of the `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` namespace. There is the caveat that generic function arguments default to `System.Object`, and that other F# types which may form incomplete patterns (e.g. union cases, records) are not included.

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
let funString o =
    let rec loop nested t =
        if FSharpType.IsTuple t then
            FSharpType.GetTupleElements t
            |> Array.map (loop true)
            |> String.concat " * "
        elif FSharpType.IsFunction t then
            let fs = if nested then sprintf "(%s -> %s)" else sprintf "%s -> %s"
            let domain, range = FSharpType.GetFunctionElements t
            fs (loop true domain) (loop false range)
        else
            t.FullName
    loop false (o.GetType())

let foo x = x
funString foo
// val it : string = "System.Object -> System.Object"
```